# How to build libraries via conda on colab.research?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory

So I want to use `python-occ` library. It requires `conda-forge` to be build. I try to install it in [basic notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#scrollTo=qtrmw-iPr-uP)

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p=conda3
!export PYTHONPATH=./conda3/lib/python
!export PATH=./conda3/bin/:$PATH
!conda install -y -c conda-forge -c dlr-sc -c pythonocc -c oce pythonocc-core
```

Yet it will install a package into condas python. How to make oit install package into global python or use its python\libs folder for cels interpritation?

So what one must do to build/install stuff with `conda` in `colab`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -y --prefix /usr/local -c <<<your wish>>>>

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The `-p` argument when executing the installer is not used correctly. It should be:

```
bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p conda3
```

instead of:

```
bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p=conda3
```

You're actually installing conda in the folder `=conda3`. Since the output you see is the message:

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`...
```

you probably have another install of conda (done with pip) in your system python.

**EDIT following the OP's edit**

First of all, I would like to say that it is not good practice to entirely change the question with an edit. Please ask a new question if you encounter new problems !!
I think you do not understand how conda works. It creates virtual environments which you can activate or deactivate. Your question:

> Yet it will install a package into condas python. How to make oit install package into global python or use its python\libs folder for cels interpritation?

makes no sense since installing a package into global python (not in a virtual environments) has nothing to do with conda. Furthermore you state:

> It requires conda-forge to be build.

`conda-forge` is a channel in conda. It is only a repository where packages are located and available for download. You don't "install" conda-forge, you put it as a channel (option -c) when you want to download a tool from this repository.

Having said this, here is how I would solve the problem.
After having installed Anaconda (btw, you didn't change the code concerning the -p option like I describe above), you create a virtual environment that will host all the tools you need:

```
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge -c dlr-sc -c pythonocc -c oce pythonocc-core
```

then you activate your environment to access the tools you just installed

```
source activate myenv
```

Now, you should have access to everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

I once needed a library that was available only through Conda too. My solution is that

- `!pip install` all the requirements of that library
- unzip(decompress) the conda file i.e. [pythonocc-core-0.18.1-py36hdfe9f0f_110.tar.bz2](https://anaconda.org/pythonocc/pythonocc-core/0.18.1/download/linux-64/pythonocc-core-0.18.1-py36hdfe9f0f_110.tar.bz2) into the right directory.

And it worked for me.