# install conda package to google colab

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory, miniconda

I try to install packages from anaconda to google's colab.

But it doesn't work. The whole thing is voodoo magic.

The following code is in one cell.

Notebook's cell:

```py
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local/
!rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!conda install -y --prefix /usr/local/ ujson aiohttp tqdm
import sys
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = "/usr/local/miniconda3"
os.environ['PATH'] = '/usr/local/miniconda3/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
import ujson
```

Result:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ujson'
```

If I go into a bash shell with "!bash" and then run the "bash's" python, I can import ujson in that python. But, if I directly import ujson in the "notebook's" python, it doesn't work.

The methods here doesn't seem to work anymore

- [How to build libraries via conda on colab.research?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202649/how-to-build-libraries-via-conda-on-colab-research)
- [What's the latest conda version compatible with Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828329/whats-the-latest-conda-version-compatible-with-google-colab) suggests the following, which doesn't work now:

```
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local ujson
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/")
print(ujson.dumps({1:2}))
```

What is the latest hack that would work?

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Comment: ujson, aiohttp, and tqdm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 2 problems that must be solved:

- ujson will normally upgrade to python 3.7, must avoid this.
- path to conda library is changed, must update it.

For 1, you need to add `python=3.6` to `conda install`.

For 2, you need to add path to `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Here's the new code

```py
# same
!wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
# update 1
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local python=3.6 ujson
# update 2
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
# test it
import ujson
print(ujson.dumps({1:2}))
```

Comment: Is "srsly" seriously part of it? Yup. It is.

Comment: How did you find that "srsly" part? What if they change the path later?

Comment: That works for `ujson`, but not `aiohttp`: `!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local python=3.6 ujson aiohttp`

Comment: I just find wherever `ujson` is with `!find / -name 'ujson*'`.

Comment: Other libraries are still at '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', so must add it as well (just updated above code)

Comment: replacing the `srsly` line by `sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/")` makes it work for both `ujson` and `aiohttp`

Comment: Oh, great! now it's less ugly. I've updated the answer as you suggest.

Comment: @korakot this one is not working at the moment. it's giving error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ujson'``` can you help me out here

Answer (score 3):

In the google colab, Jupyter IDE, try executing:

```
!pip install ujson
```

This worked for me before. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Unless you are wanting to use conda for multiple environments, like testing a new package, !pip install is the easiest method. I have found that installing conda is more difficult, and only works for one notebook at a time...

Answer (score 2):

#If any one want to implement using google collab just run this before compiling other cells

!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh

!chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh

!bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/'